# Add table in existing DNN Database

Tags: dotnetnuke

I am Currently working on DNN based website. I want to add new table for my custom module to keep record of login and registration info of profile. For that does anyone knows which fields are required for any table in DNN? I want to use database which I assigned at DNN installation. And how to retrieve data from table which I have created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chris handled the table requirements, here is a little about accessing the database...

Using DAL2 to access your database in DNN is really easy.  It helps you connect to the database and preform the CRUD operations.  Follow the MyObject.cs and MyObjectRepository.cs model and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 5):

You should really go through the Module Development wiki for DNN, the Task Manager series will do you wonders for understanding DNN (ignore that it says it is for DNN5, it will work just fine for DNN7 as well)

http://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/page/module-development

There are no "fields" required by DNN when you add a table, as a developer you can choose what you want included.

Answer (score 1):

for older dnn versions http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12853/Creating-a-DotNetNuke-Module-For-Absolute-Beginner

Please check http://christoctemplate.codeplex.com/ for dnn 7+ module development

Answer (score 0):

Besides Chris Hammond's tutorials and module template (IMHO, some of the best contributions ever to the DNN developer community), there are a couple of other extremely good tools to add to your DNN developer toolbox.

- Mitchel Sellers' Professional DotNetNuke Module Programming book ([http://www.amazon.com/Professional-DotNetNuke-Programming-Mitchel-Sellers/dp/0470171162](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470171162))
- Scott Wilkinson's series of tutorials on DNN Module Development [DNN Hero](http://www.dnnhero.com/Videos/DNNModuleDevelopment-TheBasics.aspx). (www.dnnhero.com)

Note that neither of these are free, but are well worth having!

Comment: Agreed, the resources at DNNHero are definitely worth the time and money for the DNN developer who is getting started and looking for some basic help.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with all above but for a quick example of how to use PetaPoco for your DAL, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35749594/4574668